# Forearms exercises without weights

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, forearm

Do you have any sports or body weight based exercises to improve forearm strength ?

To explain a bit my requirements, I'm travelling a lot and I do not always have the opportunity to access weights or other materials. I want to be able to perform those exercices regularly without too much equipment.

The purpose is globally to balance the size of my biceps / forearms. I have naturally small wrist (and I know I can't really do anything one this point) and forearms. I'm boxing 5 hours per week and I feel some weakness in my forearms during the sessions.

Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason you don’t want to use weights? Would you be open to using other things like bands/cables, hammers, tires, chairs, etc?

Comment: Could you also add for what purpose? Why are you looking for such exercises? That's not necessary information, but it could help people give you better answers or point out alternatives or perhaps flaws in your regular program

Comment: @JustSnilloc I have updated my question to give you more context about it.

Comment: @Raditz_35 same have updated my question to give you my goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that requires you to grip something and hold on, is a forearm exercise. Could be as simple as hanging from a bar (or a branch), or picking things up off the ground. Doesn't need to be weights like in the gym. Could be thick branches, could be rocks. Could be a suitcase full of... rocks.

As far as sports go, I would highly recommend climbing and/or bouldering. It's pretty much a be-all end-all of forearm-builders. Gymnastics, pole dancing, horse racing, baseball to name a few others.

Really, carrying anything in your hands is a forearm exercise. I don't know how gung-ho you are about it being bodyweight based, but I take it to mean you don't have gym equipment at your disposal.

As far as bodyweight goes, it's hard to come up with much other than climbing and hanging from things.

Comment: I agree, however I want to add that holding and gripping is all wrist flexion. It would be good to add some wrist extension exercises as well.

Comment: Oh, that's actually a good point, yeah. Something I've neglected for myself, if I'm honest.

Comment: Thanks for those advises ! I'll try to work on that.

Comment: Just to follow on from what @MichaelC. said, Ripper bands are great to work the extensors, and are easy to carry around. I keep some on my desk at work and do several sets throughout the day. Definitely helped with an elbow issue and to add a little size.

Answer (score 3):

There is a piece of equipment that is called expander. Just google it like "expander wrists". It helps strengthening your grip and forearms and can be easily used on the go. It can be in different forms. I prefer doughnut rubber one. They can be in different hardness and sizes.

Also, there is a thing called Powerball. It looks like a ball inside of a doughnut. You spin the ball to it's maximum and then try to hold it. Due to asymmetric muscle contractions and trying to keep ball straight forearms get stronger (kinda' like planking does for your core).

Answer (score 1):

While it's "minimal equipment" versus "no equipment", Indian club drills involving the wrists are good for developing your wrists and forearm. Without the formal clubs, any stick will do. I used to do Escrima, and when I didn't have the actual sticks, I'd go for any somewhat weighty cylindrical object I could wrap my hand around and work my rotations. I suspect you'd get most of the same benefits with a more flexible tool, like a weight at the end of a rope.